# Error: "Could not find a part of a path" using Directory.GetDirectories function in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a procedure where files are uploaded to server from client system by giving a folder path in Textbox in **ASP.NET**.
I have tested it in local machine which works fine. When i deployed in IIS on server and tested it from client system it gives me error "Could not find a part of a path C:\Path"

The following line of code gives error.

```
string[] Dir = Directory.GetDirectories(@"" + tbx_path.Text);
```

Here ***tbx_path.Text*** is a TextBox where user input e.g

> D:\folder Name

Comment: can you write your physical path?

Comment: Physical Path is **D:\Folder Name\**

Comment: Does the IIS user have sufficient privileges to that folder (check app-pool)?

Comment: User do not need to access server Drive, user from client to have select his/her own system directory just like FileUpload ASP.Net control.